# Get authentication token and user information from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook Login for Android. It works. I can log in through the emulator. However, I need to send back information to my Rails Rest API. Upon facebook callback success, I want to send back the access token, the provider ("facebook"), the uid, facebook user name, facebook user email and the facebook image icon.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    Log.i("AUTHENTICATION TOKEN", String.valueOf(loginResult.getAccessToken()));
  }
```

Logcat shows the following:

```
I/AUTHENTICATION TOKEN: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, contact_email, email]}
```

How do I get the information I need `onSuccess`?

Comment: _“I want to send back the access token, the provider ("facebook"), the uid, facebook user name, facebook user email and the facebook image icon.”_ – no, don’t do that. Anyone could send requests with fake id, name and email to your API. Send the access token only (and maybe `facebook` as well, if you need to discern it from other types of tokens), and then make a server-side API request using that token to get the rest of the user details.

Comment: @CBroe good point, I'll take that into consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the access token obtained using `LoginResult.getAccessToken()`,

You need to call the Facebook Graph api using the access token received. From the [SDK Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph),

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync()
```

The JSONObject `object` will contain the required user information provided the user has granted all the necessary permissions to your application

The list of fields available for user can be seen [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

Comment: This code only gives me an id and a name. But where is the uid, email and facebook icon? It is not in the result set.

Comment: How do I get the UID ? That's the most important part.

Comment: The id field is the unique id for the user and is specific to your app. Check the link I posted on the last line of the answer for the list of fields available

Comment: I don't see the facebook image icon on that link. I need the facebook user's icon. I am able to get it on oauth2 with their web api.

Comment: I eventually found how to add the picture: parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(large)");

Comment: Yeah the `picture` field contains the user profile picture. I wasn't sure earlier what you meant by 'facebook image icon' that's why didn't add it to my answer. Glad you found it in the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Log.i("AUTHENTICATION TOKEN", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
```